# Need to check the procedure below (Get_ClientDetails), to know if its correct

Tags: sql-server

Need a second eye on this procedure, as it been issuing an error.
The procedure is to insert data froman xml string into a table.
The table name is SL_UnitizedScheme.SpoolUnitizedScheme, and the XML syntax is as follow:

```
String<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<Clientname>Joy</Clientname>
<Account>3452672</Account>
<Amount>50000</Amount>
<EmployerCont>20000</EmployerCont>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_ClientDetails]
(@XML  XML
)

AS

INSERT INTO k2.[dbo].[SL_UnitizedScheme.SpoolUnitizedScheme]
            ([ClientName]
           ,[Account]
           ,[Amount]
           ,[EmployeeCont]
           ,[status])


SELECT
value('(ClientName/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as ClientName,
value('(Account/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as Account,
value('(Amount/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as Amount,
value('(Employee/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as EmployeeCont,
'Copied'

FROM @XML.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table')
as Table(Table)

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS 'Rows'



GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, and it's not helped by using 'table', a reserved keyword, or that the names in your SELECT don't match those in your XML. Try:

```
SELECT
MyTable.value('(Clientname/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as ClientName,
MyTable.value('(Account/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as Account,
MyTable.value('(Amount/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as Amount,
MyTable.value('(EmployerCont/text())[1]','varchar(100)') as EmployeeCont,
'Copied'
FROM @val.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table') as MyData(MyTable)
```

Comment: Thanks MartW...Would try your input now.

Comment: Thanks MartW. your input was helpful.